# Add Dalvik byte code to existing APK with Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, apk, bytecode, dalvik

My company asked me to create a dalvik bytecode injector in delphi in order to pass a piece of code in its existing apps. Basicaly it's a code that displays ads in the main activity.
So here is my question, is there a way to do that in delphi ? I'm working on the interface to make something very easy to use:

- User select an apk file
- User select type of ads to add
- Code is added into the apk
- A new apk is generated and saved

I assume that the ads cpde should be stored as a bytecode format.

I hope someone could help me.

Regards.

Comment: if its your apks, why not just add to source and recompile? If its not your apks, then should you really be modifying someone elses work?

Comment: It's the company's apps but this tool is supposed to be used by the commercial service with no or only few programming skills.

Comment: There's no question here. You need to ask a specific question. See the [faq].

Comment: If it is your apk, and you are developing all the modifications in layouts for the adds wouldn't it be easier to just set some values in your project and teach commercial service to change a simple variable that allowed an ad to display and then rebuild the app?

Comment: Closed as "not a real question"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the life easy for the commercial service, consider building the project using Apache Maven.

If it uses Maven as build tool, the Delphi application only needs to modify the Maven POM file to configure it (by adding the required JAR dependency for the ads). This can be done using built-in XML libraries which Delphi provides.

The operator then only needs to trigger a rebuild and thats it.

Android projects can be built with Maven (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/)). With Maven, the projects are also independent of an IDE.

Comment: Thank you very much. Best solution are often the simplest.